# Conexion desde asp.net Core a Base de datos con Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, mvc, asp, entity-framework-core

Hola gente les vengo a comentar un error que me sale y no le encuentro solucion.

Estoy haciendo un curso de ASP.net CORE y cuando llegue a la parte de usar el entity framework core lo voy entendiendo y todo pero haciendo todo exactamente como lo hizo la persona en el curso me tira errores.

### Primero, crea un archivo .cs y en este crea el DbContext y un constructor:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace mvc.Models
{
    public class EscuelaContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Escuela> Escuelas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Alumno> Alumnos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Asignatura> Asignaturas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Evaluación> Evaluaciones { get; set; }
    }


    public EscuelaContext(DbContextOptions<EscuelaContext> options): base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

---

En este paso ya me tira estos errores:

- A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods (CS0116) [mvc]
- Method must have a return type (CS1520) [mvc]
- 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments (CS1729) [mvc]

Luego en el archivo Startup.cs configura el servicio usando un delegado de la siguiente forma:

```
services.AddDbContext<EscuelaContext>(
                options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName = "testDB")
                );
```

y me salta este error: The name 'databaseName' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) [mvc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El constructor de tu clase EscuelaContext se encuentra fuera de la definición de la clase.

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    namespace mvc.Models
    {
        public class EscuelaContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Escuela> Escuelas { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Alumno> Alumnos { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Asignatura> Asignaturas { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Evaluación> Evaluaciones { get; set; }

          //El constructor debería estar dentro de la definición de la clase de esta forma
          public EscuelaContext(DbContextOptions<EscuelaContext> options): base(options)
          {

          }

        }
    }
```